# MySql error with a query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm writing a web application and now I have a problem

This is my `database_connect.php`:

```
<?php
     $host = 'xy';
     $user = 'xy';
     $pass = 'xy';
     $db = 'xy';

     $dbconnect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("error");
     mysql_select_db($db) or die("error");   
?>
```

I am trying to establish connection to the database and insert some data with the following code:

```
<?
    function addChapter(){
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <br>
    <input name="chapter" type="text" value="Naslov">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Potrdi">
</form>

<?php
        if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
            $chapter = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chapter']);

            if( $_GET['stran'] == 'fizika' ){
                $table = 'tblphysics';  
            }else if( $_GET['stran'] == 'kemija' ){
                $table = 'tblchemistry';    
            }   

            $chapter_id_query = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query("SELECT chapter_id FROM ".$table." ORDER BY chapter_id DESC LIMIT 1") );
            $chapter_id = $chapter_id_query['chapter_id'] + 1;  

            if( ($chapter != "") && ($chapter_id != "") ){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (chapter, version, chapter_id) VALUES ('$chapter', '1', '$chapter_id')";

                $neki = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("<p class=\"msg warning\">Napaka pri ustvarjanju poglavja.</p>");  

                echo '<p class=\"msg done\">Poglavje uspešno dodano.</p>';
                //mysql_close($dbconnect);
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/a4896862/public_html/functions.php on line 81

Line 81 is

```
$neki = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("<p class=\"msg warning\">Napaka pri ustvarjanju poglavja.</p>");
```

I know I should be using `PDO` or `mysqli`, but this will be just temporary, but it needs to work so i can continue

Anyone has any idea what is going wrong? It is causing no problem when reading from the database.

Comment: you are using the extremely outdated `mysql_query` etc. ! STOP THAT NOW !

Comment: The `$dbconnect` variable is in another scope. Also you don't need it if there's only one connection.

Comment: save the planet, use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: It's temporary and not public, mysql will suffice for my current use

Comment: @UrosHercog: add `global $dbconnect;` after `function addChapter(){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `$dbconnect` argument, since the first query works as intended without it (did it ?).

```
$neki = mysql_query($sql) or die('...');
```

But, seriously, I doubt that solving issues in some outdated mess will be faster than starting database_connect.php all over. You will get much more quality answers if you use technologies that are still supported.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't include your `database_connect.php` in your second file *(that contains the function)*. Try adding the following line before `function addChapter()` :

```
include 'database_connect.php'; // This is correct if the files are in the same directory...
```

Comment: I am including the file

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second paramater `$dbconnect` as it may not be in scope.

Does it work without it?